# What is the best way to install OpenCv in Fedora?

Tags: linux, opencv, fedora, fedora-23

I tried compiling it from source, but it turns out many libraries are missing like the Nonfree. Is it advisable to install it with dnf ? I have Fedora 23

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo dnf install opencv opencv-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

On fedora you can install Opencv simply by:

```
[root@localhost ML]# dnf install opencv
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'Dropbox', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:24:09 ago on Mon 27 Nov 2017 
04:56:00 PM IST.
Dependencies resolved.

Total download size: 1.6 M
Installed size: 10 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best way would be

```
dnf install opencv
```

since the package is in [official repositories](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/opencv).

Comment: nope..it is not the appropriate way if u wish to use certain libraries like the "nonfree"